# JPAContainer with EntityManager getting error: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/persistence/em

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, vaadin

I'm a bit confused.
I'm @Inject-ing a custom component into a @CDIView.
The component has its PersistenceContext injected

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

So far everything fine. If I look at it in debug, the EntityManager exists, I can even query the JPAContainer and get a result but when the View loads in my Application I get a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/persistence/em

So I wonder: Why?
Why is there a lookup when I passed a EntityManager in the first place?
Is there some bit of configuration I missed? Is passing a Injected EntityManager in the JPAContainerFactory discouraged?

```
16:51,367 SEVERE [com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler] (default task-44) : java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/persistence/em -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module."web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env.persistence.em
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.jndijta.Util.getEntityManager(Util.java:35)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.jndijta.CachingMutableEntityProvider.getEntityManager(CachingMutableEntityProvider.java:59)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.LocalEntityProvider.doGetEntityManager(LocalEntityProvider.java:226)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.LocalEntityProvider.doGetEntityCount(LocalEntityProvider.java:510)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.CachingSupport$FilterCacheEntry.getEntityCount(CachingSupport.java:157)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.CachingSupport.getEntityCount(CachingSupport.java:826)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.CachingMutableLocalEntityProvider.getEntityCount(CachingMutableLocalEntityProvider.java:130)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.JPAContainer.size(JPAContainer.java:912)
at com.vaadin.ui.Table.containerItemSetChange(Table.java:4565)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.JPAContainer.fireContainerItemSetChange(JPAContainer.java:262)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.JPAContainer$1.filtersApplied(JPAContainer.java:179)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.filter.util.AdvancedFilterableSupport.fireListeners(AdvancedFilterableSupport.java:99)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.filter.util.AdvancedFilterableSupport.applyFilters(AdvancedFilterableSupport.java:222)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.filter.util.AdvancedFilterableSupport.removeAllFilters(AdvancedFilterableSupport.java:275)
at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.JPAContainer.removeAllContainerFilters(JPAContainer.java:984)
at org.sportunion.BenutzerView.<init>(BenutzerView.java:207)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator$ClassBasedViewProvider.getView(Navigator.java:340)
at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:559)
at org.sportunion.MainPanel.<init>(MainPanel.java:21)
at org.sportunion.LogintoStartView.<init>(LogintoStartView.java:55)
at org.sportunion.LoginView$1.buttonClick(LoginView.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1008)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:364)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.click(Button.java:353)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button$ClickShortcut.handleAction(Button.java:471)
at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:238)
at com.vaadin.event.ConnectorActionManager.handleAction(ConnectorActionManager.java:81)
at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:233)
at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleActions(ActionManager.java:216)
at com.vaadin.ui.UI.changeVariables(UI.java:397)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:603)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:422)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:79)
at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:151)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/persistence/em -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module."web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env.persistence.em
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:184)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:237)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.vaadin.addon.jpacontainer.provider.jndijta.Util.getEntityManager(Util.java:31)
    ... 81 more
```

**UPDATE**

this is how my web-project `persistence.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="sportunion1">
   <jta-data-source>java:/Sportunion1</jta-data-source>
   <class>org.sportunion.project.domain.Admins</class>
   <class>org.sportunion.project.domain.Log</class>
   <class>org.sportunion.project.domain.Users</class>
   <class>org.sportunion.project.domain.Nas</class>
</persistence-unit>


</persistence>
```

and this is how my ejb-project `persistence.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="ejb">
   <jta-data-source>java:/Sportunion1</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="5"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and this is my log before the error:

```
    2016-04-17 22:44:51,404 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 41) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location C:\jboss\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\data\content\dd\2b865703eb79c7de40d506b137977cea1a84bf\content
2016-04-17 22:44:51,428 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
2016-04-17 22:44:51,428 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
2016-04-17 22:44:51,428 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 191) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2016-04-17 22:44:51,694 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 201) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#sportunion1'
2016-04-17 22:44:51,709 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 200) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#ejb'
2016-04-17 22:44:51,725 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0010: Stopping weld service for deployment web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
2016-04-17 22:44:51,725 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 200) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#sportunion1'
2016-04-17 22:44:51,725 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 201) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#ejb'
2016-04-17 22:44:52,631 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war) in 1212ms
2016-04-17 22:44:52,641 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
2016-04-17 22:45:04,982 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for sportunion1
2016-04-17 22:45:04,986 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for ejb
2016-04-17 22:45:05,767 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war) in 13133ms
2016-04-17 22:45:05,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
2016-04-17 22:45:13,482 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for sportunion1
2016-04-17 22:45:13,494 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for ejb
2016-04-17 22:45:14,057 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 204) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#ejb'
2016-04-17 22:45:14,057 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 204) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: ejb
    ...]
2016-04-17 22:45:14,057 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 205) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#sportunion1'
2016-04-17 22:45:14,073 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 205) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: sportunion1
    ...]
2016-04-17 22:45:14,182 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
2016-04-17 22:45:14,213 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named AdminsService in deployment unit deployment "web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" are as follows:

    java:global/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/AdminsService!org.sportunion.project.AdminsService
    java:app/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/AdminsService!org.sportunion.project.AdminsService
    java:module/AdminsService!org.sportunion.project.AdminsService
    java:global/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/AdminsService
    java:app/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/AdminsService
    java:module/AdminsService

2016-04-17 22:45:14,213 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named UsersService in deployment unit deployment "web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" are as follows:

    java:global/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UsersService!org.sportunion.project.UsersService
    java:app/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UsersService!org.sportunion.project.UsersService
    java:module/UsersService!org.sportunion.project.UsersService
    java:global/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UsersService
    java:app/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/UsersService
    java:module/UsersService

2016-04-17 22:45:14,229 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named NasService in deployment unit deployment "web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" are as follows:

    java:global/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/NasService!org.sportunion.project.NasService
    java:app/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/NasService!org.sportunion.project.NasService
    java:module/NasService!org.sportunion.project.NasService
    java:global/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/NasService
    java:app/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/NasService
    java:module/NasService

2016-04-17 22:45:14,229 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named LogService in deployment unit deployment "web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" are as follows:

    java:global/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LogService!org.sportunion.project.LogService
    java:app/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LogService!org.sportunion.project.LogService
    java:module/LogService!org.sportunion.project.LogService
    java:global/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LogService
    java:app/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/LogService
    java:module/LogService

2016-04-17 22:45:14,791 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
2016-04-17 22:45:14,798 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
2016-04-17 22:45:14,798 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
2016-04-17 22:45:14,814 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
2016-04-17 22:45:14,814 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
2016-04-17 22:45:14,814 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
2016-04-17 22:45:14,892 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 204) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#ejb'
2016-04-17 22:45:14,908 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 204) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2016-04-17 22:45:14,939 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 204) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-04-17 22:45:15,033 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 206) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#sportunion1'
2016-04-17 22:45:15,064 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 206) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2016-04-17 22:45:15,080 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 206) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-04-17 22:45:15,924 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Initializing AtmosphereFramework
2016-04-17 22:45:16,047 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Installed AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler mapped to context-path: /*
2016-04-17 22:45:16,047 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Installed the following AtmosphereInterceptor mapped to AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler
2016-04-17 22:45:16,063 INFO  [org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) META-INF/services/org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework not found in class loader
2016-04-17 22:45:16,110 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.util.VoidAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
2016-04-17 22:45:16,141 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
2016-04-17 22:45:16,172 INFO  [org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) JSR 356 Mapping path /{path}
2016-04-17 22:45:16,172 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint for path /{path}
2016-04-17 22:45:16,172 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint for path /{path}/{path0}
2016-04-17 22:45:16,172 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint for path /{path}/{path0}/{path1}
2016-04-17 22:45:16,172 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint for path /{path}/{path0}/{path1}/{path2}
2016-04-17 22:45:16,172 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint for path /{path}/{path0}/{path1}/{path2}/{path3}
2016-04-17 22:45:16,172 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptors
2016-04-17 22:45:16,172 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
2016-04-17 22:45:16,188 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
2016-04-17 22:45:16,188 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
2016-04-17 22:45:16,188 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
2016-04-17 22:45:16,188 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Dropping Interceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor
2016-04-17 22:45:16,188 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
2016-04-17 22:45:16,188 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
2016-04-17 22:45:16,204 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
2016-04-17 22:45:16,204 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
2016-04-17 22:45:16,204 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
2016-04-17 22:45:16,204 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208)   org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
2016-04-17 22:45:16,204 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
2016-04-17 22:45:16,204 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Using EndpointMapper class org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper
2016-04-17 22:45:16,204 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
2016-04-17 22:45:16,204 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
2016-04-17 22:45:16,219 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
2016-04-17 22:45:16,219 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Shared ExecutorService supported: true
2016-04-17 22:45:16,219 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Messaging Thread Pool Size: Unlimited
2016-04-17 22:45:16,219 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
2016-04-17 22:45:16,219 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
2016-04-17 22:45:16,219 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
2016-04-17 22:45:16,235 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Invoke AtmosphereInterceptor on WebSocket message true
2016-04-17 22:45:16,235 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) HttpSession supported: true
2016-04-17 22:45:16,235 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
2016-04-17 22:45:16,235 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport running under container: WildFly 1.0.2.Final - 1.2.9.Final using javax.servlet/3.0 and jsr356/WebSocket API
2016-04-17 22:45:16,235 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Atmosphere Framework 2.2.7.vaadin1 started.
2016-04-17 22:45:16,235 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
2016-04-17 22:45:16,250 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 208) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2016-04-17 22:45:16,391 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 41) WFLYSRV0013: Redeployed "web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
2016-04-17 22:45:16,391 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 41) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" with deployment "web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
2016-04-17 22:45:16,407 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 41) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location C:\jboss\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\data\content\cf\25dce1c34f9d240c649dd8fe101db0b3929e9b\content
```

and here a picture of my project structure:

[image]

Comment: Further up in the log, does wildfly say persistence.xml is read and understood? Is the creation of persistence unit logged?

Comment: Could you please provide the contents of your *persistence.xml*?

Comment: I believe you're missing the indication of your persistence unit name: `@PersistanceContext(unitName = "sportunion1")`

Comment: I have changed it but I get still the same error as above :/

Comment: First, I'd advise you to not access your database directly from the *view*. Delegate its access to your EJB and let it deal with all database interactions. This way, you'll only need one *persistence.xml*.

Comment: I have changed this, now I have just one _persistence.xml_ in my EJB and I still get the same error ... :/

Comment: @Dominik: 'm not sure it'll help, because you can actually run queries in debug, but anyway, my datasource in persistence.xml looks like this: `<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myDataSource</jta-data-source>`, maybe specifying full path will reduce chances for confusion in the lookup. Also in the UPDATE section, you still have two persistence.xml, while you claim now to have only one. If you still have two I recommend to get rid of one to reduce complexity.